# SQL query to SQL Server 2005 remotely using Borland Delphi

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi, delphi-7

What is the simplest way to execute a SQL query to a SQL Server 2005, remotely, using Borland Delphi?

In this case, I am using Borland Delphi 7.

The simplest way means, if I must use 3rd party component, it should be integrated in the application (not separate/complicated installation).

The thing is, I want to be able to check if the remote SQL server is alive.

I know, we can use network "ping", but that does not mean the SQL server is fully accessible and functional.

Thanks in advance for any tips :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Simplest

1. Drop a `TADOQuery`component on your form.
2. Fill out the `connectionstring` property (or use the `...` build button).
3. Put your SQL Statement in the `SQL` property.
4. Set your components `Active` property to `True`.

#### Better

1. Use a `TDatamodule`.
2. Use a `TADOConnection` component.
3. Link your `TADOQuery` component to the `TADOConnection` component.
4. Activate your query in runtime when needed io in Designtime. Active Connections or Queries in Designtime usually end up being a waste of CPU cycles when running your application.

#### Console Application

```
program SimpleSQL;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  ADODB,
  SysUtils;

var
  qry: TADOQuery;
begin
  qry := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    qry.ConnectionString := 'AConnectionString';

    // Update
    qry.SQL.Text := 'UPDATE YourTable SET FieldX = FieldY';
    qry.ExecSQL;

    // Select
    qry.SQL.Text := 'SELECT FieldX FROM dbo.YourTable';
    qry.Open;
    qry.First;
    while not qry.Eof do
    begin
      Output(qry.Fields[0].AsString);
      qry.Next;
    end;
    qry.Close;    

  finally
    qry.Free;
  end;
end.
```

Comment: Is this possible with a console app? Because my application is a console app.

Comment: @ewlung: no it isn't. I have added a simple console application example to execute an update and select statement.

Comment: For a console application, make sure to call 'CoInitialize(nil);' (use ActiveX unit) to initialize OLE. Then again, since you use ADODB, the OLE system also gets initialized.

Comment: I also found this is useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918016/delphi-7-ado-need-basic-coding-example