# How to connect to a MySQL server with Delphi

Tags: mysql, delphi, odbc, ado

I know how to use ODBC to connect to a MySQL database on the same machine, but now I want to know how to connect to a MySQL database on another server across the network.

Comment: Maybe the answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918016/delphi-7-ado-need-basic-coding-example can help you.

Answer (score 3):

Write the database computer's name or IP-address after `Server=` in the connection string.
For example:

```
Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User=myUsername; Password=myPassword;Option=3;
```

more examples here http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql#p31