# Storing a color in sql

Tags: mysql, delphi, delphi-7

I am using delphi 7

I want my system to have an option to change the color of say a panel and when the user closes the program and opens it again, the color should still be there.

Is there a way to save the new color in an sql column and when the programs oncreate procedure fires, it will get the color desired from the sql field.

If this is possible, how?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? How to store in a db field. What data type it should have? how to do the whole thing?

Comment: How to store it into a db field and how to retrieve the color

Comment: Question is, how can you represent a color in terms of `INT`, `BLOB`, `VARCHAR`, that is to say, in a SQL type. How do you construct a color in your code?

Answer (score 6):

The Color of the components in Delphi are represented by the `TColor` type (`TColor = -$7FFFFFFF-1..$7FFFFFFF`)  which can represented by an `Integer`. So only you need create a `INT` Column in your MySQL table and to set and get the value. If you are new accessing MySQL from Delphi , you can try the answer to this question [`Delphi 7: ADO, need basic coding example`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918016/delphi-7-ado-need-basic-coding-example/2918812#2918812)