# DELPHI exception calls EAccess Violation

Tags: delphi, ms-access, exception

There was a question similar to this however the user was using something way more advanced so I was quite confused.

This is the procedure the exception flares up. Specifically on the ADOCon.connected line. I am using the dbgo stuff and Microsoft access for my database.

The exception I am getting is: EAcessViolation. I'm wondering what mistake I've made to cause it and how to solve it. I have run the procedure on both with a pre-existing database and a new one. When there is a pre-existing database the exception is one the 19th line and without it is on the 14th line. As a user has mentioned, I have read the documentation however I am still confused on how to solve the error. The error is definitely here as this is the first piece of access I call.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs,DB, ADODB,ComObj;

type
 TForm1 = class(TForm)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
var
ADOCom:TADOcommand;
ADOCon:TADOConnection;
ADOQ:TADOQuery;
nameDB:string;
db:OLEVariant;

begin
namedb:='Brill.accdb';
if not fileexists(namedb) then
  begin
    db:=createOLEObject('ADOX.Catalog');
    db.create('Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='+nameDB+';');
    db:=null;
  ADOCon.connectionstring:='Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='+
    nameDB+';';
    ADOCon.connected:=True;
    ADOCon.loginprompt:=False;
  end
else
  ADOCon.connectionstring:='Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='+
  nameDB+';';
end.
```

Comment: What the eacessviolation means and what caused it and to fix it, sorry forgot to add it

Comment: Am I safe to assume that you read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.EAccessViolation)? Clearly that's always the first place to start. Assuming that you did read the documentation, what part of it did you not understand? Once you understand what an access violation is, you'll be able to do some debugging. Obviously we can't debug your code. And we certainly can't identify for certain the problem in your code when you don't provide a [mcve].

Comment: I've tried it with and without an existing database. When a database exists it raises on the AdoCon.connected=true line and when it doesn't it raises on the connection string.

Comment: So you didn't read the documentation then. Why not?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan because I was still confused after reading the documentation. That procedure is the minimum relevant code. It is the only code that connects/creates to the database. I have given the exception and where in the procedure it appears (I am aware that the exception can be raised after the mistake).

Comment: If you have read the documentation (which I doubt you did) you should say so and point out the specific parts that you don't understand.  And, no, this code is not enough. You'd need a [mcve]. We've been round this loop many times before. What part of [mcve] don't you get? Have you tried compiling the code in your question? You'll find it doesn't compile because it is not **complete**.

Comment: Rather than OLE access I would use ADO components (that you maybe mixed in some way, hard to say).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I will give you the exact code you need to replicate the issue. I am sorry. The edit above is a minimal, complete, and vereifable example that you can copy and paste to get the exact exception.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have read the documentation. That is why I checked it with and without an pre-existing database because it spoke about the wrong memory address. I am sorry I am really new at this and don't understand many of the technical terms.

Comment: Thanks for providing enough code to answer. I could have guessed at the problem, it seemed likely that `ADOCon` was not initialized. But that's why we need the [mcve]. Then we don't have to guess.

Comment: With reference to your edits that @DavidHeffernan has been quite rightly rolling back. Your new error is not on the line `ADOCon:=TADOConnect.create(nil);`. It's on the line before. If you post a ***new question*** with a ***proper*** MCVE, you'll get an answer very quickly. NB: _You need to learn how to create a **proper** MCVE_. Your current code is ***NOT*** complete no matter how much you whine and argue that it is. To see why: 1) create a brand new project; 2) copy the code from your question **only**; 3) observe that it cannot compile, because you missing things (i.e. ***NOT*** complete)

Comment: Note that while creating your MCVE (for a ***brand new*** question), there's a strong possibility you'll suddenly spot exactly what you've done wrong. .... _And that's when you'll be well and truly on your way to **learning**_.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is riddled with errors.

When you declare variables of a particular class type  in your code, you're responsible for creating an instance of that class and assigning it to the variable before using it, and cleaning up when you're finished with it.

```
var
  ADOCon: TAdoConnection;
  ADOCom:TADOcommand;
  ADOQ:TADOQuery;

begin
  ADOCon := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
  try
    // Set up connection properties here 
    ADOQ := TADOQuery.Create(nil);
    try
      // Set up ADOQ properties and use query here
    finally
      ADOQ.Free;
    end;
  finally
    ADOCon.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Also, your use of the `db: OleVariant` (and all code related to it) is doing absolutely nothing. You get an instance, assign properties to that instance, and then throw it away, which means you can just delete that variable and the three  lines of code related to it entirely; they serve zero purpose.

Of course, the better solution than any of the above is to add a TDataModule to your form, drop a TADOConnection and TADOQuery on it, set the properties in the Object Inspector or the OnCreate of the datamodule. You can then move that datamodule into the list of available forms, move it up to be created before your main form, and have access from anywhere in your app that uses that datamodule, and the datamodule will free everything properly when you exit your application. It also separates all of the database code from your user interface, cleaning up your code considerably.

Comment: Thank you! I had been using ADOQ.create and .free when I was using queries in other parts of my code. Should I be setting it up in this procedure since it opens the database or not? Also do I need to do that with ADOCom?

Comment: You have to set it up after setting up ADOCon, and free it before you free ADOConn. I can't see the rest of your code that isn't in your question, so I can't offer any advice about how you should do things specifically in your app.

Comment: I changed my code to yours and I am still getting the error now of the ADOCon line. I am going to edit in my code above

Comment: Please don't turn this into one of those extended debugging sessions. I reverted your edit. You didn't do what Ken said. You made the classic mistake that I described in my comment to the other now deleted answer. You wrote `ADOCon.Create`. That would attempt to call the method on the instance held in ADOCon. But you've not made an instance yet. You need to assign to ADOCon. You need to use the code as written in Ken's answer. Read it again. Frankly you are trying to write code that's far more advanced than your level of knowledge will permit. You can't skimp the basics.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just was pointing his solution still didn't fix the problem. I am still getting the same exception.

Comment: No. You didn't do what Ken said, as I explained in the comment above.

Comment: As @David says, my code does in fact fix the problem, and I'm absolutely certain of it's correctness (I've written it or it's equivalent with other classes thousands of times). If it didn't work for you, you missed something.

Comment: @KenWhite I am really sorry I must be doing something wrong. Can you look at my code above. I am still getting the exception on the ADOCon:=TADOConnect.create(nil) line.

Comment: Please stop asking new questions by editing existing ones. [ask], [help]

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am not asking a new question. The same exception pops up despite me changing my code to follow a solution. I followed the exact code, I am unsure why you edited it out again.

Comment: Nope. That's a different problem. We can't be expected to perform what I refer to as chain debugging. We fix the bug you ask about, and that just reveals the next one. Fix that and you are on to the next one. We are not here to debug such a chain of errors. We can answer a specific question, which Ken did. But that's it. The links that I left in my previous comment will be useful to you. Please spend some time learning more about this site. I know it is bewildering when you are new, but there are not shortcuts. Don't run before you can walk.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan it isn't chain debugging if it is the exact same problem. It is the exact same exception as I had before. My question has not been solved. All someone did was give be a solution that didn't work. I wasn't aware I shouldn't respond to solutions that don't work for me and ask why they didn't work for me. I don't know if you are confused but it is the exact same problem, as my question and I was just asking if I got his solution mixed up or wrong because I believe him when he says the solution is correct and I must have messed up on my end.

Comment: Nope. It's a completely different problem, with the same error message. It's chain debugging. What would be fine now would be for you to ask a new question with a very simple [MCVE] just containing the line `ADOCon := TADOConnection.Create(nil)` and asking why that raised an AV.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan so when a solution doesn't work, the question asker just ignored it and doesn't inquire into it? That isn't how I have seen anyone else use this platform. Also chain debugging is a term you made up, it isn't against the rules to inquire to why a proposed solution doesn't work.

Comment: Create a [mcve] as I outlined in my previous comment, and ask a question using that. Go the extra mile and make the code you post actually complete. Make it a complete console app, a single .dpr file starting with program. With a single line of code that does `ADOCon := TADOConnection.Create(nil)`. Ask why that produces an AV. Hint: I don't believe that it does produce an AV.

Comment: For instance, have a read of the code in the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918016/delphi-7-ado-need-basic-coding-example  This would suggest quite strongly that what you claim is not true, and that what Ken is telling you is fine. So, please do as I say and make that [mcve] and ask that new question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am asking why his solution doesn't work. According to the rules on here I shouldn't be posting and copying other people's code and asking why it doesn't work for me because I won't be able to explain why I did any of that. I tried to give a minimal, complete, and verifiable example on here to this user but you deleted it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am sure I messed up somewhere in this solution and from my edit I am sure Ken would be able to of spotted what I did wrong in his solution.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I did give the correct minimal, complete, and verifiable example of what happened with Kens code for me. You deleted it because of your personal preference. The rules of the website indicate clearly I shouldn't just be asking a question from code I have copied since I don't understand it.

Comment: Not really, because what you claim to have happened does not happen. Did you read the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918016/delphi-7-ado-need-basic-coding-example as I suggested? Which makes claims directly counter to yours?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes You saw my code. It was a minimal, complete, and verifiable example before you deleted it. Did you run it and where you not getting the error on the exact line I said which is the very start of this solution. Again, no doubt the solution is correct and I've messed it up in some way, I am trying to figure out where.

Comment: It wasn't a [MCVE]. All the variable declarations were missing. Again. Please do what I said. New question please. Concentrate on making it properly minimal. Once line of code should suffice. In a console application. Use the code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918016/delphi-7-ado-need-basic-coding-example as a guide for how to present an [mcve]. Remember that you are a novice, and I know how to ask and answer questions here. You are wasting your own time and missing out on a prime opportunity to learn. Continue in this way and you are doomed to remain a novice forever.

Comment: You would do far better to spend the time you are currently wasting arguing with @DavidHeffernan and Ken White by studying Ken's answer and the comments on it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I will. But I am just curious if you read my post at all. I did say I was just changing the main part and the declarations remained the same. But clearly copying and pasting two sections of code would be difficult. I will refrain.

Comment: @MartynA I had tried to but my edits got deleted by David

Comment: I did read your post. But what you claim there doesn't match the experience of so many others. Something is wrong. Most likely you didn't post your real code, or enough of it. You might think you did, but I've been here so many times with novices. Did you read this yet: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918016/delphi-7-ado-need-basic-coding-example  If you did you would know that `ADOCon := TADOConnection.Create(nil)` is fine.

Comment: Use View|Debug Windows|Call stack to see exactly where the exception occurs.  In any case, when preparing an MCVE, it is best to do it in a completely new project rather than attempting to edit your existing code, especially when the existing code is in a muddle like yours is.

Comment: @RosieMurphy: David's objection is correct. Once you've received an answer based on the code you originally posted, you can't then change the code to something else. It negates the answers you've received (just as yours got my answer downvoted). I strongly urge you to re-read the part of my answer related to TDataModule and use that instead, at least until you've got more experience with Delphi and working with classes and code.