# Start long running background process and check the status

Tags: delphi

I want to start a potentially long running background process from Delphi. I want to leave the process running independently, but first I want to check that the process started OK.

If anything went wrong on startup, I want to capture any output written to standardErr and log it. If the background process starts OK, my program needs to be able to exit and leave the spawned process running.

The psuedo code would be something like this:

```
process:=RunProgramInBackground('someCommand.exe');
sleep(1000); // Wait a bit to see if the program started OK
if process.Finished and process.ExitCode=FAIL then 
    Raise Exception.Create(process.ErrorStream);
process.Dispose; // Close any connection we may still have to the running process
Program.Exit; // Background process keeps running
```

I've looked at a few things (WinExec, CreateProcess, ShellExecute, JclMiscel) but can't find any examples for what I'm trying to do. What is the best way to do this?

I'm using Delphi 2010

The background process is a 3rd party program I don't have the source to.

Comment: Surely the 'RunProgramInBackground' could be implemented in a thread (assuming that you have the code to 'somecommand')?

Comment: This question likely needs clarified.  Is "someCommand.exe" something you have the source for or not?  Otherwise, what you do is start the process, then capture any exit codes, and then if there's no error, you wait until completion.  You can do this in a thread, of course, but a lot of what you are wanting to do needs made more specific.

Comment: @No'am It's a third party executable. I don't have the source code.

Comment: @Glenn1234 I don't want to wait until completion. I just want to check that the process started, then leave it to run by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the example No'Am linked to, and adding code to check that the process started OK. This function only checks the exit code of the background process, it doesn't read the StdErr output.

Here is what I did:

```
/// <summary> Runs a new process in the background. Waits for a short period, then checks that the process started succesfully.
/// If the process has already finished, checks the exit status. Otherwise, leaves it to run. </summary>
/// <param> ProgramName The executable name, including any parameters.</param>
/// <param> TimeOut Milliseconds to wait before checking the process has executed correctly</param>
/// <param> Directory The full path of the working directory</param>
/// <exception> Exception If the process was not started correctly or if the process was started but returned
/// an error before the timeout.</exception>
procedure ExecBackgroundProcess(ProgramName : String; TimeOut: Integer; Directory:string);
var
    StartInfo : TStartupInfo;
    ProcInfo : TProcessInformation;
    CreateOK : Boolean;
    status: Cardinal;
    theExitCode: Cardinal;
begin
    FillChar(StartInfo,SizeOf(TStartupInfo),#0);
    FillChar(ProcInfo,SizeOf(TProcessInformation),#0);
    StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
    UniqueString(ProgramName); // Required if a const string is passed in. Otherwise the program crashes.
    CreateOK := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(ProgramName), nil, nil,False,
              CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP+NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS+CREATE_NO_WINDOW,
              nil, PChar(Directory), StartInfo, ProcInfo);

    if CreateOK then
    begin
        status:=WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, TimeOut);
        if status<> WAIT_TIMEOUT then
        begin
            // Program has exited. Get exit code.
            GetExitCodeProcess(ProcInfo.hProcess, theExitCode);
            if theExitCode<>0 then raise Exception.Create('Program '''+ProgramName+''' failed with exit code '+IntToStr(theExitCode));
        end
    end
    else
      Raise Exception.Create('Unable to run '+ProgramName+' in directory '+Directory);

    CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hThread);
end;
```

Answer (score 3):

Check out this [article](http://www.delphicorner.f9.co.uk/articles/wapi4.htm). I quote: "Here is an updated and improved version of the code that allows you to choose in code whether the calling application waits until the other program closes before continuing or just carries on leaving the newly started program to its own devices".

```
procedure ExecNewProcess(ProgramName : String; Wait: Boolean);
var
 StartInfo : TStartupInfo;
 ProcInfo : TProcessInformation;
 CreateOK : Boolean;

begin
 { fill with known state } 
 FillChar(StartInfo,SizeOf(TStartupInfo),#0);
 FillChar(ProcInfo,SizeOf(TProcessInformation),#0);
 StartInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
 CreateOK := CreateProcess(nil, PChar(ProgramName), nil, nil,False,
                    CREATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP+NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS,
                    nil, nil, StartInfo, ProcInfo);
 { check to see if successful } 
 if CreateOK then
  begin
    //may or may not be needed. Usually wait for child processes 
   if Wait then
    WaitForSingleObject(ProcInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
  end
 else
  begin
   ShowMessage('Unable to run '+ProgramName);
  end;

 CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hProcess);
 CloseHandle(ProcInfo.hThread);
end;
```

Edited: after reading your comments, I suggest that you look at this previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901860/delphi-7-how-to-execute-shell-command-and-check-the-result)

Comment: The process could start OK, but then exit with an error. Perhaps I still need to call WaitForSingleObject, but with a finite timeout (e.g. 1000, as in the original question). I still need a way to read any error stream...

Comment: @awmross What has been given here is good.  What you need to do is remove the "WaitForSingleObject" call and in place there read off a pipe to see what the Error stream is.

Comment: @Glenn1234 Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @awmross I'm thinking something similar to http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/delphi/delphi.html#AppRedirectOutput  The problem I'm running into in my own example is that redirection isn't working on anything but the command prompt itself.  But it illustrates how to do it.

Comment: I had to add a line 'UniqueString(ProgramName);' before calling CreateProcess. Otherwise the program segfaulted. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/06/01/9673254.aspx

Comment: CreateProcess 2nd parameter is IN/OUT in unicode (but somehow, not in ansi). So the call will crash if the string ProgramName points to read-only memory. That happens if you call with a constant parameter or a string literal, for example. UniqueString is indeed the best fix for that problem.