# How to install JVCL packages if the installer failed when I ran it as a non-Administrator User

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, vcl, jedi, jvcl

I use Win7. I have installed Jedi VCL Components in my Delphi XE and It work correctly. However if I try to run the XE as another user account (doesn't have Administrator priveleges), the JVCL Components do not appear in the Tool Palette whereas I need to run as client user to use the RxLib Tools and Components which were installed as client user.

Is there any way to install or use the Jedi VCL Components not as the Administrator User?

Help me please...

The The appeared error message if I run bat file as regular user is :

```
[Compiling installer...]

Using Embarcadero RAD Studio XE Embarcadero Delphi for Win32
compiler version 22.0 Copyright (c) 1983,2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc. 
Fatal: F2039 Could not create output file '..\..\bin\JVCLInstall.exe' 
Failed to compile JVCL installer

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: exporting [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\CodeGear\BDS\7.0\Known Packages] as Administrator, (editing the file if needed) an reimport as user should work.

Comment: @bummi How to do that? I can't imagine how to export registry key.. :(

Comment: Run RegEdit.exe - 0 but that is a basic Windows using/tuning question, nothing about programming

Comment: that is rather weird, for i am using JCL/JVCL in Xe2 in Win7 without such problems. What is the paths for Delphi itself, JCL and JVCL ? I think you should not had run Delphi as administrator at all.

Comment: @Arioch'The what 'paths' are you meant here? Simply, I can't find the JVCL Components on the Tool Palette if I run the XE as the Client User/Guest User, not as Administrator User..

Comment: path to `dcc32.exe` of Delphi and paths to `install.bat` of JCL and of JVCL
....
Also you always can install any component in Delphi-standard way, without using custom installers at all. Thought it all is rather strange... When you try to run JCL and JVCL installers, did they requested UAC elevation ("as Adminitrator") ? They should not. You should run JCL and JVCL installers as regular user ("client"). / Afterall main actions of customs installers are not registering of components - that Delphi can do in its standard way - but settings of search paths and compiler conditionals in sources...

Comment: Also, http://newsportal.delphi-jedi.org/ is standard forum for JCL/JVCL // Also i wonder what were jcl/jvcl versions and how you obtained them and of JCL and JVCL installers worked without errors.

Comment: This person is obviously not a Windows expert, let's go easy on the Noobs.

Comment: @Arioch'The Yes..the problem is Installer don't compile the Packages if I run the Install.bat not as Admin User.. There are many packages weren't loaded correctly if I run the Install.bat as client user instead Admin User so the Wizard Installer don't appeared...

Comment: @WarrenP but Windows questions are still windows questions, they even do not  belong to Stack Overflow site, let alone "delphi" tag. Just offtopic regardless experience of the asker. // Additionally, just like i told - the question is not loading BPLs int oide, but making program run. So the person should read C++Builder (not just Delphi as he shown by tags) about compilation process, file types used and where to specify paths to them in IDE options or Project options. And just loading those BPLs is the little step that does not help much.

Comment: Topic starter should either manually compile and install all the packages (and probably make a mess of folder paths), or should investigate why his installer fails. And when topic starter just does not answer the questions... well, then he'd better BE the expert.

Comment: @Andromeda - i already asked you about paths. Please do answer.  Also what happens if you run install.bat as a regular user ? there should be error messages then. What are they ? Also install.bat merely compile and run the installer from sources - `d:\DelphiProjects\Libs\JediVCL\jvcl\install\JVCLInstall\` - You can do it from within IDE as well.

Comment: Also how did you install those `RxLib Tools and Components` ? official RxLib releases had no separate installer AFAIR and were installed in plain Delphi-standard way, whch still can be used for any library out there. Though official RxLib ended wth Delphi 5 version

Comment: @Arioch'The The Path to `dcc32.exe` is: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\8.0\bin\dcc32.exe` ... Path to JCL's `Install.bat`: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Components\JVCL347CompleteJCL241-Build4571\jcl\jcl\Install.bat` ... Path to JVCL's `install.bat`: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Components\JVCL347CompleteJCL241-Build4571\jvcl\install.bat` ...

Comment: @Arioch'The The appeared error message if I run bat file as regular user is : `[Compiling installer...] Using Embarcadero RAD Studio XE

Embarcadero Delphi for Win32 compiler version 22.0
Copyright (c) 1983,2010 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Fatal: F2039 Could not create output file '..\..\bin\JVCLInstall.exe'

Failed to compile JVCL installer

Press any key to continue . . .`

Comment: @Arioch'The I install the `RxLib` with command on cmd such as: `dcc32 -JL RtmRxCtl150.dpk`, `dcc32 -JL RtmRxDB150.dpk`, `dcc32 -JL RtmRxDB150.dpk` and `dcc32 -JL dclRxDB150.dpk` ... it succesfully installed on RAD Studio 2010 Delphi XE and BCB XE ..

Comment: paths in spaces may lead to troubles (few months ago jcl or jvcl installer could not find the compiler), and having some potentially changing files (like help) in protected area. I install it in special shortnamed folder likec:\RadStudio to avoid UAC path virtualization and such.

Comment: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Components\JVCL347CompleteJCL241-Build4571\jcl' That is it. This barely worked in Win98/Delphi5 time and definitely obsoleted now. Move all the components out of system-protected folders like \Windows and \Program Files. Make folders like 'c:\Delphi\Libs\JCL` and 'c:\Delphi\Libs\JVCL` instead.
You may additionalyl consider trying to use "on the edge" versions like GIT/SVN/nightly tarball. XE1 support is more or less stable now though, so release zips would probably work too.

Comment: "Could not create output file '..\..\bin\JVCLInstall.exe'" ...and ? it told you outright that it needed folder with right grants and `Prgram Files` is folder only be touched by admins and only very rarely, when upgrading the system. It is just bad place for your projects, including pascal libraries.

Comment: It's a noob mistake to try to Install  Jedi into `Program Files`.

Comment: Yeah.. It's my mistake to install JVCL into `Program Files` directory.. Thanks for your replies..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to Components menu, click it, and pick Install Packages. Click Add Packages.

Go to the folder where you installed JEDI and find the place where your BPLs are.

In my compuer that's `C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\9.0\Bpl`

Type this into the filter box in the file open so you can find just the packages we want to install:

`Jv*Design160.bpl`

If you don't see any files that match that then your installer did not even build the .BPL files for Delphi product version 16.0.  Note that the 9.0 number is the IDE version, and 16.0 is the package suffix and compiler major version, here for XE.  If you were using XE2 it would be major version 17.0 (so the file suffix is 170), and so on.

Here is a picture of what it looks like when the Jedi JVCL packages are installed in your IDE:

[image]

You probably also need to locate and install some JCL packages. Use `Jcl*160.BPL` as your file filter expression.

You also probably should learn about the Library Paths and go find what they were in one account, and just copy them however you like to do that. I find that using the Registry Viewer to export these keys is one way, and another is to just open the options in Delphi and copy things one at a time from one place to another.    Be careful if you use the registry editor to export and import.

Also your underlying inability to compile may be a simple matter of NTFS PERMISSIONS. If you don't know what those are, you're not going to get far on Windows.  Also from comments, it seems you don't know better than to try to install SOURCE CODE into `C:\Program Files` folders, and then expect those folders to be writeable by regular users too.   Seriously,
man, don't put code there, as Arioch said, that's not where Code goes.

Comment: Now, I got new problem.. If I try to compile the project which using TJvDBGrid Component on it form, the compiler is showing Error Message: [ILINK32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'JVDB.LIB' .. can you describe to me what was actually happened here? Help me please :(

Comment: you did not set the search paths in projects's compiler object or in IDE's library options.

Please, read your C++ Builder documentation about compiler paths. 
Warren just read the documentation for you once above, but should he re-tell you ALL the documentation ?

Comment: https://www.google.ru/search?client=opera&q=%5BILINK32+Error%5D+Fatal:+Unable+to+open+file&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest

Comment: Andromeda: Did you even TRY to run the installer again? I think it will install just fine even without Admin priveleges.   Programming is about trying things. DId you try? :-)